# Springboot CRUD with Redis Cache saves additional information along with object data

Tags: spring-boot, redis, crud

I have a simple springboot application performing CRUD operation.
Upon receiving a rest api POST request, the application saves the Customer data in REDIS cache. However while saving the data, the application seems to be saving additional information along with the object data as shown below,

1. "com.bopanna.cachetest.redis.model.Customer"
2. "com.bopanna.cachetest.redis.model.Customer:2"

Here I can see the content of the Customer object with key value as 2 using the command
**HGETALL com.bopanna.cachetest.redis.model.Customer:2**, for which it displays

1. "_class"
2. "com.bopanna.cachetest.redis.model.Customer"
3. "id"
4. "2"
5. "name"
6. "Tom"
7. "place"
8. "Ohio"

I can't seem to use the same command on **com.bopanna.cachetest.redis.model.Customer**. Doing it results in
**(error) WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value**

What does this additional information store ?
Also, how can I code as to not save these additional information?
Why cant I view the data with just the **GET com.bopanna.cachetest.redis.model.Customer:2** command ?

My code looks like this,

```
@Data
@RedisHash
public class Customer {
    @Id
    Integer id;
    String name;
    String place;
}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/Customer")
public class ApplicationController {
    @Autowired
    CustomerRepo customerRepo;

    @PostMapping(value = "/customer")
    public @ResponseBody Customer create(@RequestBody Customer customer) {
        customerRepo.save(customer);
        return  customer;
    }
}
```

```
public interface CustomerRepo extends CrudRepository<Customer, Integer> {}
```